# Updating model field in django not working properly at runtime

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model Product and another model Damaged. In the Damaged model I add the number of damaged quantity of a certain product. Now, I need that damaged_quantity to be reduced from the stock field in the Product model when the foreign key matches. The code works when I have added a damaged_quantity in the Damaged model but when there is no damaged_quantity of a certain product it throws type error so I tried like this in template but it is not working.

> models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def current_quantity(self):
        return self.quantity - self.damaged_set.all().aggregate(sum=Sum('damaged_quantity')).get('sum', 0)

class Damaged(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    damaged_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

> template

```
    <td>
        {% for damage in damaged %}
                {% if damage.product_id == product.id %}
                {{product.current_quantity}}
                {% else %}
                {{ product.quantity }} # else part not working properly.
                {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
    </td>
```

Comment: what is the type of ```self.damaged_set.all().aggregate(sum=Sum('damaged_quantity')).get('sum', 0)``` ?

Comment: its type is `int`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's because your queryset returns None when empty. So, you should do something like that:

```
    @property
    def current_quantity(self):
        damaged = self.damaged_set.all().aggregate(sum=Sum('damaged_quantity')).get('sum', 0)
        if not damaged:
           damaged = 0
        return self.quantity - damaged
```

Comment: Is the type of damaged ```int``` when damaged_quantity = 0? Check if it's not returned into a list or something else that makes this typeError.